# how to configure ms sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have just downloaded SQL Server 2005 express edition from here:

To be used as a database for a vb.net program.

But I'm confused in using sql server. I do not know where to start from here:

http://screencast.com/t/ZTdiMDU5

Do I have to create the database in vb.net?-->

http://screencast.com/t/ZjRlYjkx

If not, where could I create the ms sql database? I'm a beginner and I want to learn.

Please help.

Do you have any tutorials there that could help a beginner like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed Visual Studio 2005, you probably installed SQL Server 2005 express with it. Re-Run the installer, if you haven't

If you already have SQL Server 2005 express installed, download and use SQL Server Management Studio http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en

You can find programming tutorials for beginners here: http://www.asp.net/learn/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database using the SQL Server Management Studio. Most configuration can be done through this application. If your server is ready for the prime time, you can use SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable remote TCP/IP connections.

Comment: how do I create a server?I just want to use ms sql server 2005 for database programming in vb.net

Comment: The server will be created when SQL Server is installed. As Andrei Drynov said, it comes with Visual Studio 2005 and 2008.  

If not installed, you can download and install it from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=220549b5-0b07-4448-8848-dcc397514b41&displaylang=en  

There is a good writeup on how to install it here: http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-6102265.html  

You will also need to install the management studio.